# How to Execute Command stored in variable from a file

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, command-line-interface

> cmd="cd /home/pi"
>
> $cmd and eval "$cmd"

This is working in CLI but I am interested to run a command from a variable stored in some file. In that file I wrote

> $cmd and eval "$cmd"

and execute file from CLI but it shows error. Any solution??

Comment: Which error ? And what about the exec-family ?

Comment: I have no idea regarding exec-family.
The error it shows is syntax error......

Comment: Read about exec / execve.

Comment: I am using CLI of Raspberry so coding environment I use is Python....

Comment: Import os.subprocess perhaps better?

Comment: no use for "import os.subprocess" :(

Comment: Thanks icbytes.....Its working!
in file we should 
import subprocess
the sample command to be execute from file
subprocess.call(["ls","-a"])